Animated Javascript canvas line with random amplitude representing internet traffic
How can I implement these animated lines in the screenshot? They should be endless

I tried to do this, but it only turns out to be a sine wave that follows a predictable trajectory, but I need a random trajectory


const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let xOffset = 0;
const frequency = 0.02;
const speed = 2;

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, canvas.height / 2);

  for (let x = 0; x < canvas.width; x++) {
    let currentAmplitude = (x / canvas.width) * 100;
    let y = canvas.height / 2 + Math.sin((x + xOffset) * frequency) * currentAmplitude;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  }

  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.stroke();

  xOffset += speed;

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="400"></canvas>




You can look in to Perlin noise for creating a random signal that doesn't go all over the place. You'll have to play around a bit with the variables to get different signal shapes you like.
Here's an example, using just the first perlin noise snippet I found on google.


for (const canvas of document.querySelectorAll("canvas")) {
  const bumpyness = 4 + Math.random() * 4;
  const seed = Math.random() * canvas.width;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

 
  let i = 0;
  const Point = () => (perlin.get(seed + i++ / canvas.width * bumpyness, 1) + 1) / 2 * canvas.height;

  const points = Array.from({ length: canvas.width }, Point);

  function animate(dt) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, points[0]);

    points.push(Point());
    points.shift();

    for (let x = 1; x < points.length; x++) {
      const y = points[x];
      ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    }

    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.stroke();


    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }

  animate();
}
canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: .5rem;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
<script src='http://joeiddon.github.io/perlin/perlin.js'></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="60"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="60"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="60"></canvas>



